# Java : Automatically set array dimensions based on number of columns in CSV file

Tags: java, csv

Is there a way for java to read a `csv` file, determine the number of columns and then create an `array` or `arraylist`(s) with the appropriate dimensions?

EDIT:  More specifically what is the method for determining the number of columns in a `csv` file without opening it beforehand?

Comment: Why bother with dimensions ? `ArrayList` is dynamic

Comment: Yes, there is. Read in the file, determine how many columns there are, and size an array with that number. What specific issue are you having?

Comment: @DaveNewton:  I guess I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of columns in a csv file without opening it beforehand.

Comment: @ringbearer: ArrayList is dynamic in both length and width?

Comment: How on earth could you determine how many columns are in a file without opening the file? (Unless it uses a naming convention, say. But ew.)

Comment: @screechOwl, Yes, depending on the heap size.

Answer (score 3):

When you read the file line by line, before creating an array or array list you can count number of columns. Basically, it's a question of your algorithm, not of the technology.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using a CSV parsing library like [openCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) (others are available).

CSV is a deceptively complicated file format, so take advantage of the code others kindly provide to us.

Quick examples of "valid" CSV:

```
"I'm",a,valid,"csv,line,with,four,columns"
```

In countries like Germany they use ";" as the separation character

```
"I'm";a;valid;"csv,line,with,four,columns"
```

And this nasty one.... Fields could contain newlines :-(

```
"I'm";a;valid;"csv,line,
with,four,columns"
```